# Resharper truncates unit test messages in the output window and also shows parent exception message

Tags: silverlight, resharper, mstest

I'm running R# 7.1.2 and trying to test a SL project using the MS unit testing framework. My tests run fine in R#, but the output messages include the parent exception (not just my custom message) and they are truncated:

e.g. instead of

```
"No user context set"
```

I get

```
Test method Some.Quite.Long.Namespace.And.Test_Method_Name threw exception: Microsoft.VisualStudio.T
```

I wouldn't even mind if the message included the assembly qualified method name...

```
Test method Some.Quite.Long.Namespace.And.Test_Method_Name threw exception: Microsoft.VisualStudio.Blah.Blah.Blah, No user context set
```

but instead it's truncated!

Obviously, it's difficult to tell if the unit test failed due to an expected assertion or some other issue (like a config issue)

I can't find anything in the R# options which relates to this...

Does anyone else have this problem or know what the issue might be? I suspect it's something to do with the reference to the unit testing framework as I also can't use the `[ClassInitialize]` attribute (it complains about wrong type for arg #1 in signature even though the type expected is the correct one!)

Comment: what options do you have selected in `Resharper->Options->Tools->MSTest` ?

Comment: `Enable MSTest support` and `Use Test Run Configuration specified in metadata file`. Not got `Run tests with MSTest.exe` checked

Comment: what is the significance of silverlight? what happens when you run a basic unit test (eg `throw new Exception("foo");` from a new Unit Testing assembly project?

Comment: Think it may be SL related. I've not tried it in a standard .NET lib. I just thought I'd throw it out there since I'm a bit tied for time at the moment and my machine is absolutely crawling!